# How to find _id and verify if it has an existing key in mongoose please?

Tags: mongoose

I want to find user by its _id and verify if he had or not btc in his wallet?

```
users =
{
  "_id": "6515a3cb181eafcdd26460ce"
  "wallet": [
    {
      "btc": 0.1
    },
    {
      "bnb": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

I try this

```
const id = "6515a3cb181eafcdd26460ce"
const query = await users.findOne({ _id: id, wallet: {$in: [`btc`]} });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your documents will be stored in terms of the `btc` object but this will cover you just in case the value of `btc` is zero (`"btc": 0`) or if the `btc` property is not there.

This will match if all conditions are true:

1. The `_id` is a match
2. The document has an object in the wallet array with a key `btc` that is not `null`
3. The document has an object in the wallet array with a key `btc` that is not equal to zero.

```js
const id = "6515a3cb181eafcdd26460ce" 
const query = await users.findOne({
  _id: id,
  wallet: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $and: [
        {
          btc: {
            $ne: 0
          }
        },
        {
          btc: {
            $ne: null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

See it working [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BgyrykabTLz). You will notice I have included a few different objects. One without the an object containing `btc`, one with a `"btc":0`, and one with a `"btc":null`.

**Edit**: If you want to update the value then you can increment the `btc` value using `$inc` and then check that the update was successful. The `findOneAndUpdate` method returns `null` if no document was found so you will know if it was unsuccessful. I have included the code below to get you started:

```js
try {
   const user = await users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: "6515a3cb181eafcdd26460ce",
     wallet: {
       $elemMatch: {
         $and: [
           {
             btc: {
               $ne: 0
             }
           },
           {
             btc: {
               $ne: null
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   }, { $inc: {"wallet.$.btc": 0.5 }}, {new: true});

   if(!user){ //If null
      // No user found, update not successful
      // Respond to front-end
   }else{
      // Repond to front-end with success
   }
}catch(err){
   console.log(err);
   //Handle error response to front-end
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working. I have another one question please. How can I increment the btc value under the wallet if it exists? Thank you.

Comment: You can use the `findOneAndUpdate()` see [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html). The first argument will be the query (which you now have) then the second argument will be the update object containing anything you want to update e.g `{btc: 0.2}`. If you get stuck just post another question and someone will help you out.

Comment: Thank you, Im trying like: 'const coin = btc; const amount = 2; await db.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$inc: {[`wallet.$.${coin}`]: + amount}})' but btc amount won't increment. Helps me please.

Comment: You could try `const doc = await users.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$set: {"wallet.$.btc":  0.2}}, { new: true});`

Comment: I have tried with $set but monngose say `"BadValue"`, maybe it's because I'm just set user schema as `wallet: Array`, really I don't know how to set this type of schema as wallet will contain arrays of object like `wallet: [{btc: 1}, {bnb: 200}]`. 

Comment: Code should work. Run this [example](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/J5PDox1rVqm) test.

Comment: It's working thanks, but my probleme is that: Firstly, I want just verify if  the user have **btc** or not with `const query = await userModel.findOne({
      _id: id,
      wallet: {
        $elemMatch: {
          $and: [
            {
              usdt: {
                $ne: 0
              }
            },
            {
              usdt: {
                $ne: null
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    });` after `if(query)` I want to increment **btc** value not **set** new value `else` I just push **btc: amount** into **wallet** array